# Is there a "best practice" when passing a function from one class to another where neither one inherits from the other?

Tags: python, class

I have two classes which do **NOT** inherit from each other but one does need to call functions from the other. I made a simplified example using a *Bathroom* class and a *Shower* class.

The first method passes in the function as an one of the init arguments. The second overrides a variable after the first class is created.

## Method 1

This seems like the proper way to do this but it can be tedious to have to pass in the function for every instance of *Shower1* This would have to also be done for every other class that would require that function too; like *Sink*, *Rug*, *Toliet*, etc... It would be even more tedious if multiple functions needed to be passed into each one.

```
class Bathroom1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def AddToItems(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)
        print('br1', str(self.items))

class Shower1:
    def __init__(self, AddToItems):
        self.AddToItems = AddToItems

        self.AddToItems('Shower1')

bathroom1 = Bathroom1()
shower1= Shower1(bathroom1.AddToItems)
```

## Method 2

This gets the same results as method 1 and I believe this would also be less tedious when there are multiple classes or multiple methods that need to be passed in. Rather than having to pass in the arguments for every new object created it would only have to be done once. But I'm not sure if this is considered "correct" or if it will lead to other problems.

```
class Bathroom2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def AddToItems(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)
        print('br2', str(self.items))

class Shower2:
    AddToItems = None
    def __init__(self):
        self.AddToItems('Shower2')

bathroom2 = Bathroom2()
Shower2.AddToItems = bathroom2.AddToItems
shower2 = Shower2()
```

I could use inheritance to make it easier to add other classes like *Sink*, *Rug*, etc...

## Example With Inheritance:

```
class Bathroom3:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def AddToItems(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)
        print('br3', str(self.items))

class BathroomItem:
    AddToItems = None

class Shower3(BathroomItem):
    def __init__(self):
        self.AddToItems('Shower3')

class Sink(BathroomItem):
    def __init__(self):
        self.AddToItems('Sink')


bathroom3 = Bathroom3()
BathroomItem.AddToItems = bathroom3.AddToItems
shower3 = Shower3()
sink = Sink()
```

Is there a recommended way to do this?

Comment: I can't understand why you would do any of these. Normally you would pass the whole bathroom object, not one of its methods. Can you give a real use case for this?

Comment: Why does the item need to be able to add itself? Just use `bathroom1.AddToItems(shower1)`.

Comment: There could be any number of different collections you might want to add somethihng to, the item doesn't need to know about all of them.

Comment: I think this kind of question about dependencies between classes would be more appropriate for [softwareengineering.se].

Comment: @DanielRoseman would passing the entire bathroom object take more memory?

Comment: @Barmar It would be easier to add the object automatically when crated. I would have to have 2 lines of code each time to crate the class if not, one to create the class and one to add it to the list of items.

Comment: You're creating an unnecessary dependency, that a shower has to be in a bathroom, and it can't be in other things as well.

Comment: Variables in python are references, so they are all the same size, whether they refer to an empty list or a multi-megabyte string.

Comment: @Dave1551 no, why would it?

Comment: @Barmar when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal here is to add items to the bathroom, why not just pass the bathroom instance in whenever you're creating a new object?

```
class Bathroom:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def AddToItems(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)
        print('br', str(self.items))

class BathroomItem:
    def __init__(self, bathroom):
        bathroom.AddToItems(self)

br = Bathroom()  # bathroom.items == []
item1 = BathroomItem(br)  # bathroom.items == [item1]
item2 = BathroomItem(br)  # bathroom.items == [item1, item2]
```

Comment: Would this use more memory? If yes it seems like this may lead to issues with large scripts. If not then this is definitely a better way to do it.

Comment: @Dave1551 I guess that depends on the type of script you need to use; but what I can say is that this is a fairly standard approach to this type of problem.